# PersonalNotes field showing as null when retrieving contacts through outlook REST API

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi

When I create a contact in outlook 365 for desktop (using windows or mac), when retrieving it through the API using the endpoint https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts or https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/contacts they seem to not come over with the PersonalNotes field populated (its coming as null). If I create a contact through Office 365 web this field comes over fine.